In Sequoia, how do I navigate modals with only the keyboard
On a modal like this:

How do I hit "no" only using my keyboard?
When I hit enter, it defaults to yes. Tab doesn't work, neither do the arrow keys. How do I select the no option without having to use the mouse / trackpad?
I do have keyboard navigation enbaled, but somehow it doesn't do anything. What other setting is there that needs to be activated?


I am unable to reproduce in 15.1 with Keyboard navigation enabled. Have you restarted your computer to ensure that the setting saved successfully? https://share.cleanshot.com/Gdg0wCc8 It's possible that the issue was resolved in 15.1, but seems unlikely
